# postfix rewrite a specific from domain address

Tags: postfix

Postfix version: 2.10.1

We have applications that send mail as app@domain.com. These applications send to a postfix mail server, to relay mails.
I would like to rewrite the from address to be app@newdomain.com.
I realise we need to change it on the app, but these changes will only go live in a few months, so I am trying to rewrite in postfix in the intrim

I have been able to rewrite all mails to app@newdomain.com but i just want mails from app@domain.com to be rewritten.

vi /etc/postfix/sender_canonical
adding the following

```
/.+/    app@newdomain.com
```

This works, but changes all mail sent from the Postfix server to app@newdomain.com

I have also tried adding

```
 /app@domain.com/ app@newdomain.com
```

But this does not seem to do anything

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

```
vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Add

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

Then open the following file

```
vi /etc/postfix/generic
```

Add the following

```
app@domain.com app@newdomain.com
```

Postmap the file

```
postmap /etc/postfix/generic
```

Now restart or reload postfix to apply the changes to main.cf

```
service postfix restart
```